# Is there a faster approach than caching data between request? (heroku django app)

Tags: django, heroku, caching, memcached

I have a question regarding caching and performance for my django app on heroku.

- django 2.2.9
- python 3.7

In my django-app I use different ajax request which use the same queryset (first request is number of results according to the filter set, then it requests a table, then pictures).

For performance reasons I use a cache on server side instead of querying each time the database.

In development I used the LocMemCache of Django, which is really fast and convenient.

On heroku it is really slow (I don't know why actually). So I changed to memcached which is recommended by  django and by heroku.

I tried "MEMCACHED CLOUD" and "MemCachier" (both heroku addons). but they are very slow, also when I use them locally (locmem: < 1 sec; memcached: > 5sec)

**Questions**:

- Should I use different approach instead of caching? (I thought of sessions, but there I cannot store query sets. And I'm not sure if its really faster, as it saves on the database or in cache)
- If caching is the right approach. How can I speed it up?

Thank you!

```
#settings
CACHES = {

    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_bmemcached.memcached.BMemcached',
        'TIMEOUT': 60 * 60,
        'LOCATION': os.environ['MEMCACHEDCLOUD_SERVERS'].split(','),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'username': os.environ['MEMCACHEDCLOUD_USERNAME'],
            'password': os.environ['MEMCACHEDCLOUD_PASSWORD'],
        }
    },
    'local': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'
    }
}
```

and in caching

```
#caching

from django.core.cache import caches
from models import ImpactEvent
from datetime import datetime

cache_l = caches['local']
cache = caches['default']


qa = ImpactEvent.objects.all()

#queryset evaluated on purpose
cnt_ies = len(qa)
share_d = {
        'q_ie': qa,
        'cnt_ies': cnt_ies, #are 200 entries
    }

def get_cache_test(name):
    start = datetime.now()
    cache.get(name)
    print('cache get', datetime.now() - start)
    start = datetime.now()
    cache_l.get(name)
    print('cache get_l', datetime.now() - start)

def set_cache_test(name, value):
    start = datetime.now()
    cache.set(name, value)
    print('cache set', datetime.now() - start)
    start = datetime.now()
    cache_l.set(name, value)
    print('cache set_l', datetime.now() - start)
```

performance results

```
# results
set_cache_test('string', 'value')
cache set 0:00:01.070784
cache set_l 0:00:00.000089

get_cache_test('string')
cache get 0:00:00.282374
cache get_l 0:00:00.000109

#dictionary with queryset
set_cache_test('share_d', share_d)
cache set 0:00:09.692612
cache set_l 0:00:00.044507

get_cache_test('share_d')
cache get 0:00:00.221846
cache get_l 0:00:00.052196
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching is the solution to your problem. You can easily serve more than 90% of your queries through cache alone.

The next question is where do you cache your queries.

The fastest is local cache. i.e. on the same machine where your application is running. The major disadvantage of doing this is the complexity involved in invalidating the cache in case of an update. If you have your application running on 10 servers and the data gets updated in the database you would have to make sure that the cache is evicted from all servers, which will be a pain.

So it is always better to have a centralized caching server like Memcached or redis. Also make sure that the caching servers are on the same network as your applications. Network between the servers should be as fast as possible.

If you think your cache is very slow, make sure your cache is working. The connection that you are creating is a singleton connection. As in you are creating the connection once in your application.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you pratikvasa! Yes, my caching is slow (9.6 seconds with memcached, compared to 0.04 seconds caching with LocMem, which I cannot use in production). How can I improve my cache? I did not find usable information regarding memcached or memcached cloud (which is the service I use on heroku). Thank you!

Comment: Where and how is memcached hosted?

Comment: I added the addon "MemcachedCloud" on heroku. I have the free plan with 30MB memory and 1 dedicated database called Memcached Cloud/AWS/us-east-1/30MB. https://redislabs.com/lp/memcached-cloud/ 
Sorry, I do not know a lot about caching. Which information do you need? Thank you

Comment: It's mainly slow on setting the cache (about 10 seconds) but quite fast on getting the cached value (0.1 s)

Comment: Ok..make sure that the cache server is in the same region as your application servers. (Assuming your application is also hosted on AWS). If your write time is high, does it include database time. If not then I would check if the object that you are storing is large or not (more than 2-3 MB)

Comment: Thanks. When the app is running on heroku (where cache and application server both are hosted on AWS) writing is fast (about 100 ms). So this was the main problem. 10 seconds is from my development server (without database time). The object is only about 200 bytes.